# Arrays inside arrays arent copied/.slice(0)-d correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say we have a variable a. We want to save it for later, so we make a copy of it with .slice(0):

```
var a = [[1,2]]
var b = a.slice(0)
```

This should work, right? Well, if we do this:

```js
var a = [[1,2]]
var b = a.slice(0)
console.log(b + " - before change")
a[0][1] -= 2
console.log(b + " - after change")
```

It returns:

```
1,2 - before change
1,0 - after change
```

However, if we change variable a to just [1,2] it works normally. Why does this occur?

Comment: Because `slice` doesn't make a copy?

Comment: `.slice()` is a shallow copy. If there are non-primitives in the array, they are copied by reference, not by value.